# Did they ever explain the way Evie's looks changed in-universe?

Tags: the-mummy

When they changed the actress playing Oracle mid-sequels in Matrix, [they made up an in-universe explanation for it](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/37137/why-did-the-merovingian-destroy-the-oracles-shell).

Was there an in-universe explanation for a change of actress playing Eviel in the Mummy sequel #3 (*The Mummy: Tomb of the Dragon Emperor*), when Rachel Weisz was replaced with Maria Bello?

Comment: Related: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/87515/whats-the-in-universe-explanation-for-the-change-of-face-of-bruce-banner/87520#87520

Comment: The closest they came was a throw-away line to the effect of "I feel like a new woman".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## No

In terms of canon, all we have to go on is the content of the film itself.  No in-universe reason was given in it for the very drastic changes in Evie's appearance and persona.

In *Matrix Revolutions* (which you refer to), the Oracle was a program and that was something that was easily exploited to explain the change in her appearance.

However, Evie is a flesh-and-blood human being.  True, there are various supernatural forces at work in the *Mummy* trilogy, but no appeal was made to those as a means of explaining Evie's changes.