# Is there any known reason why the actress for Evie was changed in the third movie?

Tags: the-mummy

Is there any known reason as to why the actress for Evie was changed in *The Mummy: Tomb of the Dragon Emperor*?

From what I saw in other films, ... it is a very unusual step for that to happen at all so I guess the reasons are appropriate.

Comment: [Related](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/107371/58193) but from the in universe perspective.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Rachel Weisz reportedly dropped out because "the script was crap".

> Bad news Mummy fans. Rachel Weisz has officially dropped out of The Mummy 3.
>
> You might remember a few months ago we were the first place to break the scoop that there was trouble with Mummy 3. **At the time we told you that Weisz was hesitant to take part in the third sequel because of severe problems with the script.** Of course shortly after we posted that story, Universal called us to refute it. It looks like their claim that everything was fine with Mummy 3 was nothing more than PR spin. We had it right.
>
> The same source that broke that original info to us contacted me tonight to update us on why Weisz left. Our source says, **“the script is still in the same shape that it was the last time I told you about, meaning that its still crap and Weisz finally took the high road out of there.”** It sounds like even if they do manage to get other key cast members to participate, it won’t matter. It will take a miracle to make The Mummy 3 good.
>
> <sub>[Cinema Blend, Rachel Weisz Leaves Mummy 3](https://www.cinemablend.com/new/Rachel-Weisz-Leaves-Mummy-3-4912.html)</sub>

Other sources report she also didn't want to leave her infant son and that the problem with the script was she was supposed to be the mother of a 21 year old which would make her character too old.

> Director Rob Cohen has claimed that Rachel Weisz turned down a role in the third Mummy movie because her character was "too old".
>
> The 37-year-old played Egyptologist Evelyn Carnahan in 1999's The Mummy and 2001 sequel The Mummy Returns, but declined to appear in upcoming sequel The Mummy: Tomb of the Dragon Emperor.
>
> Her representative said the actress did not want to leave behind two-year-old child Henry to spend five months shooting in China.
>
> However, Cohen claims Weisz was furious that her character has an adult son in the new film, telling Heat: "I got a very angry phone call from her agent, saying she'll never play the mother of a 21-year-old. I said, 'OK, good, fine, bye.'"
>
> Weisz has been replaced by Maria Bello in the third instalment, which is due for release in August.
>
> <sub>[Digital Spy, Weisz criticised for 'Mummy' decision](https://www.digitalspy.com/movies/a95411/weisz-criticised-for-mummy-decision/)</sub>

Answer (score 1):

According to wikipedia Rachel Weiss did not like the script and had given birth shortly before so the role was recast.